# rails 3 model relation with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I got these three models:

Projects, Organisms and Sequences

Each sequence is unique and belongs to an organism. An organism can have many sequences. So far, it works fine.

The problem I am struggling with is the association in my projects model:

I need to select one organism and one of the to the organism associated sequences to the project. But also, an organism can have many projects.

I was following these instructions : [has_and_belongs_to_many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/29/has_and_belongs_to_many-associations-in-ruby-on-rails/). But it fails, when I try save my form data. When I try to "build" it in the console, it even fails:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > project = Project.new

 => #<Project id: nil, name: nil, organism_id: nil, sequence_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :002 > project.organism.build

NoMethodError: undefined method `organism' for #<Project:0x56117c8>
```

What's wrong with what I'm doing?

Maybe i am following the wrong path here. im not very good in database design, so i need some help obviously :) What i'd like to have is something like project.organism and project.sequence as well as sequence.organism and origanism.sequences. You see, the three models are close connected to each other. The background is, that a rake task will update the list of the organisms and the associated sequences regulari form NCBI database. Therefore i cant just "save" the data in the projects model, i have to link them to other tables.

EDIT: my Project Model looks like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :organisms
  #has_one :sequence  
end
```

note: i still have no idea, how to make the sequence available to the project.

and the migration:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|

      t.string :name

      t.integer :organism_id
      t.integer :sequence_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

thank you four your help,
Adrian

EDIT 2:

i *think* i have solved it. I just rethought about that, and this is the more simple solution:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organism
  belongs_to :sequence   
end

class Sequence < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :organism   
end

class Organism < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :projects
  has_many :sequences 
end
```

The problem with this is only that i cant go back from sequences to projects like sequence.projects

Comment: Looks like project does not have a field or a method called organism. Show the code for the project model please :)

Comment: *updated* my post with the model.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
project.organisms.build
```

instead of

```
project.organism.build
```

You did called the association organisms after all :)